# Ionic2-Calendar now failing on the device

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic 4 based app with Angular 8 and have a strange situation that has developed. I am using [this calendar](https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar).

It seems to be similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56214875/ionic-calendar-event-does-not-load-on-device)... and you will see I have commented there asking how they solved it to no avail.

It works fine on the browser using ionic -serve and WAS working fine on my android device (I haven't gotten to iOS yet).
There was an andoid update to my phone last week and since then, the calendar page doesnt work any longer.
I have stripped out most of the code and simplified it to the extent that it (almost) works now but I have to remove the datasource object.
This leads me to believe there is something wrong with the data in the datasource which I had found before when incorrectly formatted. However, I am uncertain if this is the issue.
The startTime and endTimes come from the server and are converted from ISO strings like this:

```
  fixAppointmentTimesFromServer(appointment: Appointment) {
    appointment.startTime = new Date(appointment.StartTimeServer);
    appointment.endTime =  new Date(appointment.EndTimeServer);
  }
```

If I log out the type of object in the appoinmtents array like this:

```
this.userService.appointments.forEach( appt => {
  console.log(appt.startTime);
  console.log(typeof (appt.startTime));
  console.log(appt.endTime);
  console.log(typeof (appt.endTime));
});
```

it shows the start/endTimes as strings so I was wondering if this could be the issue, or if thats just more of the mystery that is JS Date objects..?

Or if anyone can tell me how to actually find and get into the Calendar module to debug it, then that might help?

I've added an additional:

```
    this.platform.ready().then( res => {
      ...
```

at the start of the ngOninit().

The whole start/end time thing could just be a red herring...
Any thoughts at all? Thanks

Comment: Which android version you tried in real android device?

Comment: My phone is now on Android 9.  Tbh, not sure what it was before. Is there some change in the os that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question here since I don't want others to have the same issues I had tracking this down.

The way I was fixing up the date for the ionic2 calendar wasn't adequate (apparently) as it needs a millisecond based Date Object to work properly. Different browser versions seem to operate differently.

So, the way I fix up the dates from the server now is as follows:

```
  fixAppointmentTimesFromServer(appointment: Appointment) {
    const start = new Date(appointment.StartTimeServer);
    const end = new Date(appointment.EndTimeServer);
    appointment.startTime = new Date(Date.UTC(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth(), 
    start.getDate(), start.getHours(), start.getMinutes()));
    appointment.endTime = new Date(Date.UTC(end.getFullYear(), end.getMonth(), end.getDate(), end.getHours(), end.getMinutes()));
  }
```

This converts first to a string and then converts again to get a UTC (millisecond) based Date object. Which does work.

**A word of caution however:**

**I found that when I wasn't getting the data from the server, but using the already converted data from out of Ionic Storage, it broke again.** This needing me to reconvert the data when getting it out of storage. So, this wasn't some 'funny date on the server' to JS thing, moreover a perfect example of how completely ******* up Javascript actually is!